# How to scroll to the bottom of a finite JavaScript webpage that only gives you pieces at a time as you scroll "bottom"

Tags: firefox, scrolling, webpage

You have a long webpage like

https://www.youtube.com/@JanyaAndromedaGalactic/videos

you scroll to the "bottom" and then the javascript or whatever css idk how it's made,
loads you more.  Repeat 20x it's cumbersome and suboptimal.

I see there's a Firefox add-on "ScrollToBottom" but no thanks.

Any easy way?

I know there's youtubextras that loads you a whole page and all the comments on a video
-- but I want a general and simple solution.  Without getting in the Delorian and going before javascript and css whatever ruined the internet and you had nice static pages WYSIWYG

Suppose for the question it's Firefox browser but it could be Brave or another good one.

Also I know from command line in Linux for example I could wget the url and that would probably work but maybe someone knows another way, like scrollToBottom:http://your-lame-javascript-page.htgl that would be a nice feature. I don't have time but maybe someone can propose that on the Firefox forum.

Comment: You cannot jump to the "bottom" because stuff gets loaded in while you scroll, which is why that extension keeps scrolling until you reach it.

Comment: softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is for questions like this but remember to read the help section first

Comment: @gantendo should I move it I thought it fits here I don't want a software I want to use what already exists that I have.